# Error 3728: is not a constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to alter *(not best practice?)* a SQL server database's table that was installed by a piece of software.

**Goal:**

Set a constraint on a column to be a primary key then remove it.

**Notes:**

`APPT` - Table name

`ApptId` - Column that functions as a primary key (but was not set as the primary key by the software)

**Question:**

 How to resolve `___ is not a constraint.` error message?

The command I'm trying to run (test) is as follows and should enable and disable the `ApptId` row as the primary key:

```
-- Set an existing field as the primary key
ALTER TABLE APPT
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ApptID)

-- Remove primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE APPT
DROP CONSTRAINT ApptID
```

The above command sets the `ApptID` as the primary key, however when it tries to **drop** it an **error message** is produced:

```
-- Error 3728: 'ApptID' is not a constraint.
-- Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

Why is this the case?

 when I try to view the constraints for that table using:

```
-- List all constraints for a specific table
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('APPT')
```

I get:

```
NameofConstraint           | TableName | ConstraintType
PK__APPT__EDACF695230515B9 | APPT      | PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
```

---

When I set the `ApptId` column as the primary key via Sql Management Studio the result looks cleaner (i.e. without random string)

```
NameofConstraint           | TableName | ConstraintType
PK_APPT                    | APPT      | PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
```

But this does not resolve my issue when trying to programmatically drop the primary key constraint on the `ApptId` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add primary key with out a name, SQL server generates a name for the constraint

So you are seeing the name as PK__APPT__EDACF695230515B9

In this case you need to use the generated name to drop the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE APPT DROP CONSTRAINT PK__APPT__EDACF695230515B9
```

When you added the Primary key from SSMS, it gave the name as PK_APPT

you can do the same

```
ALTER TABLE APPT
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_APPT PRIMARY KEY (ApptID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the name of the constraint?

```
ALTER TABLE APPT DROP CONSTRAINT PK_APPT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if constraint is already dropped and you are running the drop script again